# Recursive array of objects to append property children count

Tags: javascript, recursion, mapreduce

I need to recursively loop through an array of objects and each object object has a property `label` which needs to be modified to include the `children` count.

Take a look at this example:

```
const nodes = [{
  value: 'World',
  label: 'World',
  children: [{
    label: 'Europe',
    value: 'Europe',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Albania',
        value: 'AL'
      },
      {
        label: 'BeNeLux',
        value: 'BeNeLux',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'The Netherlands',
            value: 'NL'
          },
          {
            label: 'Belgium',
            value: 'BE'
          },
          {
            label: 'Luxembourg',
            value: 'LU'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}]
```

The expected output would be:

```
const expectedOutput = [{
  value: 'World',
  label: 'World (4)',
  children: [{
    label: 'Europe (4)',
    value: 'Europe',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Albania',
        value: 'AL'
      },
      {
        label: 'BeNeLux (3)',
        value: 'BeNeLux',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'The Netherlands',
            value: 'NL'
          },
          {
            label: 'Belgium',
            value: 'BE'
          },
          {
            label: 'Luxembourg',
            value: 'LU'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}]
```

This is what I have working now, but it's not working correctly because as mentioned in the `expectedOutput` above, `Europe`'s label would be `Europe (4)` and my version counts `Europe (2)` because it's ignoring the children inside Europe.

```
export const getSortedNodesWithChildrenCountLabel = nodes => {
  return nodes
    .reduce(function f (output, node) {
      if (node?.children) {
        node.label += ` (${node.children.length})`
        node.children = node.children
          .reduce(f, [])
      }

      output.push(node)
      return output
    }, [])
}
```

Comment: why has world only one as value, not four?

Comment: @NinaScholz You are right, it should be 4 indeed

Comment: I'd try recursion to get count of all children, algo would be that you start at root and create recursive function which will count count of every children of this Node and these nodes will fire also this function to calculate children and then you will add this with its parents so you get full count for every node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and get the count from the children and update `label`.

This approach mutates the data.

```js
function update(nodes) {
    return nodes.reduce((count, node) => {
        if (node.children) {
            var subcount = update(node.children);
            node.label += ` (${subcount})`;
            return count + subcount;
        }
        return count + 1;
    }, 0);
}

const nodes = [{ value: 'World', label: 'World', children: [{ label: 'Europe', value: 'Europe', children: [{ label: 'Albania', value: 'AL' }, { label: 'BeNeLux', value: 'BeNeLux', children: [{ label: 'The Netherlands', value: 'NL' }, { label: 'Belgium', value: 'BE' }, { label: 'Luxembourg', value: 'LU' }] }] }] }];

update(nodes);

console.log(nodes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A non mutating version which gets the count with an object to the outer call.

```js
function fn(count = { count: 0 }) {
    return function ({ value, label, children }) {
        var sub = { count: 0 };
        if (children) {
            children = children.map(fn(sub)),
            label += ` (${sub.count})`;
            count.count += sub.count;
            return { value, label, children };
        }
        count.count++;
        return { value, label };
    };
}

const
    nodes = [{ value: 'World', label: 'World', children: [{ label: 'Europe', value: 'Europe', children: [{ label: 'Albania', value: 'AL' }, { label: 'BeNeLux', value: 'BeNeLux', children: [{ label: 'The Netherlands', value: 'NL' }, { label: 'Belgium', value: 'BE' }, { label: 'Luxembourg', value: 'LU' }] }] }] }],
    withCount = nodes.map(fn());        

console.log(withCount);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What about a non mutating version? I'm using React to render the labels and each render it now keeps appending the child count to the label: `Europe (4)` -> next render `Europe (4) (4)` -> `Europe (4) (4) (4)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can decompose children counting into a separate recursive function:

```js
const nodes = [{
  value: 'World',
  label: 'World',
  children: [{
    label: 'Europe',
    value: 'Europe',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Albania',
        value: 'AL'
      },
      {
        label: 'BeNeLux',
        value: 'BeNeLux',
        children: [
          {
            label: 'The Netherlands',
            value: 'NL'
          },
          {
            label: 'Belgium',
            value: 'BE'
          },
          {
            label: 'Luxembourg',
            value: 'LU'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}]

const getChildrenCount = (node, count = 0) => {
  if (!node.children) {
    return 1
  }
  for (const child of node.children) {
    count += getChildrenCount(child)
  }
  return count;
}

const getSortedNodesWithChildrenCountLabel = nodes => {
  return nodes
    .reduce(function f (output, node) {
      if (node.children) {
        node.label += ` (${getChildrenCount(node)})`
        node.children = node.children
          .reduce(f, [])
      }

      output.push(node)
      return output
    }, [])
}

console.log(getSortedNodesWithChildrenCountLabel(nodes))
```